# Update links in excel: Automation error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, runtime-error

When I open an Excel workbook that I am trying to open in VBA

I get the warning:

> This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe.
>   If you trust the links, update them to get the latest data. Otherwise, you can keep working the data you have

When I run the script on the workbook mentioned above in my debugger I get:

> Run-time error ... Automation error

from this line:

```
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```

I declare `targetSheet` like this:

```
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
```

Is there any way I can still work with the source workbook as is?

Comment: Why do you need to refer to the Workbook? You can use Worksheets directly. Set targetSheet = Worksheets(1) that's all you need.

Comment: @GSazheniuk - `Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` will continue to work even after another workbook has become the active one, e.g. after a `Workbook.Open` or a `Workbook.Add`.  It would depend on where in the code the setting of the targetSheet occurs as to whether the workbook object could be omitted.

Comment: You wrote you are trying to open that workbook in VBA, are you are using `Workbooks.Open` method? Share the code including it. Better do not rely  on `.ActiveWorkbook` property, since active workbook may be changed at any moment.